# Ordering data in ASP.NET DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I have data like this in database table:

```
vehicle1 driver1 
vehicle1 driver2
vehicle2 driver3
vehicle3 driver4
vehicle3 driver5
vehicle4 driver6
vehicle4 driver7
vehicle4 driver8
```

I need to show drivers ordered by vehicles in asp.net dropdownlist. But I need to show drivers from vehicle X first where X is set up dynamically (programmatically).

So if X is vehicle3 the data in my dropdownlist would look like this:

```
**vehicle3 driver4**
**vehicle3 driver5**
vehicle1 driver1 
vehicle1 driver2
vehicle2 driver3
vehicle4 driver6
vehicle4 driver7
vehicle4 driver8
```

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Where do you add that dynamic item? I assume that the item contains of two database columns of two different(joined) tables, correct? Are both columns dynamic or only the `vehicle` part or maybe only the `3` at the end of `vehicle`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter On the page in matter I am working with specific vehicle. And I want drivers from that vehicle to be listed first in my dropdown. I can do it in aspx or in aspx.cs. So it can be defined in dropdown definition in .aspx page in where parameter or something like that. If thats what you ment.

Comment: I've asked because the best way would be to do it  in the database itself. But you've mentioned that you want to do that _programmatically_. It's still not clear why, how and where you are generating the item programmatically. It seems as if you could pass the current vehicle to the database as parameter, then you can use `... ORDER BY CASE WHEN Vehicle=@CurrentVehicle THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Vehicle, Driver`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My bad - it doesn't need to be done programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data in `SQL Server` database then select the data as required.

```
SELECT A.Vehicle, A.Driver 
FROM (SELECT Vehicle, Driver, CASE @X WHEN Replace(Vehicle,'Vehicle','')
                              THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS OrderCol 
      FROM yourTable ) A
ORDER BY A.OrderCol,A.Vehicle
```

Answer (score 0):

Order your results from the database by using
`ORDER BY Vehicle, Driver`

Then insert your dynamic items programmatically at index 0, so they appear before the data bound items.